# ESPP USA owned company UK tax query

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, shares, espp

I have been taxed on the full profit made following the sale of my shares which were purchased through an ESPP.

I purchased at 85% of day 1 cost.

I thought I would only have to pay tax on the 15% staff discount, but I have been taxed on the total profit following the sale of my shares.

The profit was below capital gains tax

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I have been taxed on the full profit, but I thought I would only be taxed on the 15% discount?  Does anyone know what amount you are taxed on when purchasing shares through an ESPP - the full profit or the discount?

Comment: Slightly confused by your use of "_I have been taxed on the total profit_", and especially your comparing this to the 15% discount. If you sold the shares as soon as you bought them, then the total profit _should be_ 15% (+/- any slight movement in price if the sale didn't happen immediately), and (from my experience of a non-ESPP, UK-only share scheme), you'd pay CGT on that figure (if above the threshold). Are you implying you've been taxed on the _full price_ of the shares at the time you sold them (e.g. as though you'd been _given_ the shares for nothing)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the plan is unqualified or qualified, and whether you met the holding requirements. From what you’ve said it sounds like you’ve been taxed as though it is an unqualified plan.

https://uk.practicallaw.thomsonreuters.com/4-565-1485?transitionType=Default&contextData=(sc.Default)&firstPage=true&bhcp=1

Possibly too late for you now in this case, but in general it is really important to seek proper advice before making transactions on things like ESPPs, share options etc and making sure you understand all the implications.

Comment: Thank you it was an unqualified plan - I sold the shares as soon as I purchased them.  WE have only been owned by the company for a year so the scheme was new to everyone.  We just thought that we would get taxed on the 15% discount  Thanks again